# Limit a view to select between two date partitions

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I wish to define a view for Google Analytics landing pages. I've tried to set this up by saving the following query as a view:

```
SELECT
  date,
  fullVisitorId AS fv,
  visitID AS v,
  h.page.pagePath AS landing_page
FROM
  `project-id.dataset.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) AS h
WHERE
  hitNumber = 1
```

In the queries that join to this view I plan to limit them to between two date partitions like so:

```
SELECT
  sessions.date,
  fullVisitorId AS fv,
  visitId AS v,
  landing_page
FROM `project-id.dataset.ga_sessions_*` AS sessions, UNNEST(hits) AS h
JOIN `project-id.dataset.landing_pages` AS landing_pages
ON landing_pages.fv = sessions.fullVisitorId
AND landing_pages.date = sessions.date
AND landing_pages.v = sessions.visitId
WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170108' AND '20170108'
```

This still appears to select a large volume of data ~5GB rather than ~60MB that would be expected for one day.

How can I re-write the view so that it only selects the relevant date partitions as defined by the consuming query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to include the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` in the view definition so that you can reference it in queries over the view. Here's an example that converts the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` to a date:

```
SELECT
  date,
  fullVisitorId AS fv,
  visitID AS v,
  h.page.pagePath AS landing_page,
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) AS sessions_date
FROM
  `project-id.dataset.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) AS h
WHERE
  hitNumber = 1;
```

Now try a query over the view:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT fullVisitorId) AS total_visitors
FROM `dataset.view_name`
WHERE sessions_date = '2017-01-08';
```

Comment: Thanks Elliot, this did the trick. Is there anyway to avoid having to specify the "WHERE sessions_date = '20170108'? I tried LEFT JOIN in the consuming query, but this still selected a large quantity of data. It feels like there should be a way, but I guess all said and done it's small potato, just trying to slim down the query as much as possible.

Comment: The issue with a `LEFT JOIN` is that if the view is on the right, `sessions_date` can end up being null (if a key doesn't exist in the view) so the filter can't be "pushed down" like it normally would. One way to avoid this is to use a subquery, e.g. `LEFT JOIN (SELECT ... FROM my_view WHERE sessions_date = ...)`.